# Finding required external symbols

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker, symbols

I am currently facing a linking error on Visual Studios C++ 2010. I know exactly that I forgot to link some .lib files against the project and it turned out to be true.

However, the problem is my project depends on another project (that I did not do) that provides header files and .lib files that have different names. And I am having a hard finding the specific lib files.

In this case, how can I find the right .lib file for the symbols I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? (dumpbin /SYMBOLS) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935183/tool-to-view-functions-exported-in-static-library

Comment: is there a some sort of auto-find method? You need to instruct Dumpbin to go for each file each time, don't you?